# How to replace ISO-8889 characters and hex representation in direct way?

Tags: bash, awk, sed, utf-8, iso-8859-1

I have an HTML file for which I want to convert the ISO-8859-1 codes to UTF-8.

sometimes, within the file, the special character appears in this format

```
&#x200
&#x203
```

and sometimes, the special characters appear in this format

```
 È
 Ë
```

In both cases I would like to replace them with the HTML indentity as below:

```
 &Egrave;
 &Euml;
```

I've tried with `awk` doing like this:

```
awk '{gsub(/\200/, "\\&Egrave;" , $0); print}' file
```

But in this case, only is replaced `È` but not its equivalent `&#x200`.

Is there a way to replace those characters in a single/direct command or is needed to consider both ways? I mean, do as follow for each character?

```
awk '{ gsub(/\&#x200/, "\\&Egrave;" , $0)
       gsub(/\200/,    "\\&Egrave;" , $0); print}' file
```

If there is a more efficient way to do it or with another tool I'm open to suggestions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You mean `&#200;` and `&#203;`, btw. `&#x200;` and `&#x203;` are very different characters.

Comment: Actually within the HTML file appear with the `x` I don't know why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way, using the perl [HTML::Entities](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::Entities) module (Available through your OS package manager or CPAN if not already installed) to convert *all* entities and non-ASCII characters:

```
$ cat example.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Testing &#200; and &#203;
    <p>Testing È and Ë
  </body>
</html>
$ file example.html
example.html: HTML document, ISO-8859 text
$ perl -Mopen=IN,":encoding(iso-8859-1)" -MHTML::Entities -ne \
    'print encode_entities(decode_entities($_), "^\n\x20-\x25\x27-\x7e")' example.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Testing &Egrave; and &Euml;
    <p>Testing &Egrave; and &Euml;
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Excellent. Thanks so much for your help.I had to install the HTML:Parser, that I found contains HMTL:Entities and it worked perfect!. One question, I don´t know almost anything about perl, what does it mean this part `"^\n\x20-\x25\x27-\x7e"`?